# System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am trying to make a .NET Core Web API but I couldn't find out a solution for my problem.

Full error is

> [ERR] An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type '"MailAlertWebApiWithEF.Data.AlertContext"'."
> ""System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I get that configuration codes from an existing database with

> Scaffold-DbContext "server=.;ConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DBModels -force -v

My configuration is:

```
 public class AlertModelConfiguration<T>:BaseEntityModelConfiguration<T,int> where T:Alert
{

    public AlertModelConfiguration(ref ModelBuilder modelBuilder):base(ref modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Alert>(entity =>
        {
            //entity.HasKey(e => e.AlertId);

            entity.Property(e => e.CreateDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.DeleteDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Detail)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(2046)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.ErrorDetail)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdateDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
        });
     }
}
```

My context is:

```
 public class AlertContext:DbContext
  {
    public AlertContext(DbContextOptions<AlertContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Alert> Users { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       
        new AlertModelConfiguration<Alert>(ref modelBuilder);
       

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

My ConnectionStrings inside at appsettings.json:

```
ConnectionStrings": {
   "AlertContext": "server=.;database=*****;poling=false;Connect 
 Timeout=60;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

When I start at debug mode the API gets stuck inside the engine layer.

My Engine and IEngine:

```
Task<CustomListEntity<Alert>> GetByIdAsync(int id);

 public  Task<CustomListEntity<Alert>> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return  CommonOperationAsync(async () =>
         {
             var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Alert>();
             predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Id == id);

             

             return new CustomListEntity<Alert>()
             {
                 EntityList = await _alertReqository.GetAll(skip: 0, take: 10, predicate: predicate,
                     orderExpression: null, rowCount: out var count, ascending: false).ToListAsync(),

                 Count = count,
             };
         }, new BusinessBaseRequest()
         {
             MethodBase = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
         }, BusinessUtilMethod.CheckRecordIsExist, GetType().Name);
    }
```

I tried my own configuration file but the result is the same. What is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error indicates that your connection string is not correct.

There is a typo in the word "pooling", try with the following connection string:

```
ConnectionStrings": {
         "AlertContext": "server=.;database=*****;pooling=false; 
                 Timeout=60;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

If still not working, make sure the server and database values are OK.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this same error, but the problem is not with the connection string, but due to some confusions like below:

In Startup.cs file, I have added the below setting which is wrong:

```
services.AddDbContext<EFCFWithExistingDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(MyDatabaseConnection));
```

Below is the right code. My error has gone.

```
services.AddDbContext<EFCFWithExistingDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabaseConnection")));
```